# Standard Objects in Salesforce?

Tags: force.com

I have created warehouse app in the salesforce using custom objects and i want to see all the standard objects.How do we see all the standard objects and can perform operations like data insertion and adding fields on standard objects ?

Is there any ebook , sites or videos by which i can learn salesforce easily ?

Comment: First Go through salesforce fundamental  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to SFDC. First Go through [salesforce fundamental](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) it gives u basic knowledge with step by step process for creating a `Recruiting App`. Then for more customizing ur App use `Visualforce` and `Apex` for coding and for that study together [Visualforce workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf%E2%80%8E) and [apex workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/.../apex_workbook/apex_workbook.pdf) .

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Go to the [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/).  There are many different useful pages, such as the [Getting Started Series](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewGettingStarted?id=000176053&language=en_US).
- You can see a [list of standard objects here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm).  You can drill into individual Objects such as [Account](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#topic-title).
- Take a look at the [Force.com Documentation page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Documentation) for links to useful developer documenation.
- Take a look at the various [Data Models](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm) such as the [Sales Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) below to get the big picture of how all of the standard Objects are related.

[image: Sales Objects]